# how to filter datagridview with user control popup

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

my user control popup on datagridview cell double click and fills `strings.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());` in user control is checkedlistbox and one button. how can i filter datagridview on button click and checkedListBox1.CheckedItems using bindingSource.filter = string.Format("LoadName LIKE '{}'", );
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need something like this:

```
var checkedValues = strings.Where(s => IsChecked(s))
                           .Select(s => "'"+s+"%'")
                           .ToArray();
bindingSource.Filter = "LoadName LIKE " + string.Join(" or ",checkedValues);
```

Where `IsChecked()` is a fake method, you should replace it with something telling you if the value is checked or not in your `CheckedListBox`.

Supposing your `CheckedListBox` items are strings, you can replace the line:
`strings.Where(s => IsChecked(s))`
with  this one:
`ceckedListBox.CheckedItems.Cast<string>()`

Comment: Hope this helped. By the way, you should accept some answer in your older questions, otherwise few people will respond to you again. It's how StackOverflow works ;-)