# How can I implement filtering in the DataGridView control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to develop an application which uses a DataGridView for showing the data from the table. And I want to add the filter row to the DataGridView. It means when the user clicks on the filter button then the DataGridView should add an empty row at the beginning of the DataGridView. And if the user inputs some data, depending on the fields which present in the DataGridView, then the DataGridView should provide the quick filtering related to the input in the specific cell input.

Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: I guess you will have to put in a bit more effort and try it on your own. Read MSDN documentation related to the DataGridView and do some experimentation...

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your question what exactly you're trying to do. In general, people are not going to give you a complete, working solution as an answer. You'll have to do *most* of the programming work yourself; we're only here to help out if you run into a snag along the way, not write your code for you.
In the future, please try to put more effort into your questions than simply posting your requirements.

That being said, you might want to check out these sample projects:

- [DataGridView Filter Popup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PopupDataGridViewFilter.aspx)
- [DataGridView Filter Popup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewFilterPopup.aspx) <sup>(yes, these are two different articles, despite having the same name)</sup>
- [Datagridview with filtering capability](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Datagridview_Fiter.aspx)
- [A Filter Dialog for a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/filterdialog.aspx)
- [DataGridView Filtering User Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewFilterUC.aspx)

Comment: The 'DataGridView Filter Popup' from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewFilterPopup.aspx appears to be an excellent option.  Appears to do exactly what I need it to do.  Thanks @Cody Gray

Answer (score 2):

This may help

[how to filter datagridview with user control popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256548/how-to-filter-datagridview-with-user-control-popup)