# How do I search for a specific cell in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I get the cell index in a DataGridView where the column header text = "something" and the row contains "somethings"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement filtering in the DataGridView control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087095/how-can-i-implement-filtering-in-the-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a DataGridView column directly by its name. You'd need to do something like this:

```
int FindCellRowIndex( string columnName, string rowContent ){
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgView.Rows){             
           foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells){
               if( cell.OwningColumn.Name() == columnName && cell.Value != null && Convert.Tostring(cell.Value) == rowContent)
                  return row.Index;
           }             
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I was trying same things but problem in your code is that when i typing col and than pres dot in drop down menu cell property missing. If i write col.Cell it gives exception : Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells'

Comment: My bad, you can't iterate over a DataGridViewColumn's cells. But you can do that with a DataGridViewRow. I corrected the code, check it out. The problem is that now it must iterate over all cells, so it's not as efficient. If anyone knows a better way, please do tell

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the [GridViewRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.aspx) and then each cell of the individual GridViewRow. If you do that, then you can get the cell's text property. Another option is to use FindControl and extract the appropriate property. You can use the `.FindControl()` method to find actual controls (label, literal, checkbox, etc) inside cells or go through them by index `GridView.Rows.Cells[index]`